# The best way to inherit from form in qt

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

What is the most preferable way of inheriting from form created in qt designer?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question

Comment: with `private` class inheritance IMO.

Answer (score 5):

There is no good direct way to inherit form itself, you'd better inherit class created for form.

```
class testBase : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testBase (QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~testBase ();

protected: // here was private
    Ui::testBaseClass baseUi; // rename this
};

testBase ::testBase (QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

also, if you want to add some other form, which is also possible, you should do some additional work:

1) Specify a placeholder for child ui in base class (some container)

2) create your child form with wizard. DO NOT pass your base class as ancestor, in wizard you should say that you inherit from QWidget.

3) after creating form for your derived class, rewrite derived to be descedant of your base.
change its constructor, line `ui.setupUi(this)` should be changed to `ui.setupUi(baseUi.placeholder)`

```
class testDerived : public testBase 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testDerived (QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~testDerived ();

private:
    Ui::testDerivedClass ui;
};

testDerived::testDerived(QWidget *parent)
    : testBase (parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(baseUi.placeholder);
}
```

also note, that derived class does not change base class form, it extends it. You would not be able to add or remove items to base form in form constructor, but container you specify as placeholder will be filled with form data of derived class.

Comment: Sure. Even QtCreator supports the inheritance approach. It is not inheriting from itself, but rather from QtDesigner-generated form-class.

Comment: well, you MAY inherit that class. but that is bad approach. it would cause name ambiguity and some other nasty things. fixed no way - no good way

Comment: Which ambiguities would that be? I don't see how it is more fragile than inheritance in general. See also http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-a-ui-file.html . (btw, personally I prefer the pointer-to-form approach; I was just questioning your claim)

Comment: i mean `class derived: public QWidget, private Ui::SomeForm, private Ui::SomeForm2`. Such double inheritance would be headache

Comment: That's also not a recommended way. One of the recommended ways is `class derived: public QWidget, private Ui::SomeForm`, without the `Form2`. Note that `Form2` is not a widget in itself, so I see no headache in that. It becomes headache only if you declare the same symbols both within the Form and the deriver, which of course would not be good practice. But headache is really not inherent in inheritance.

Comment: at first, setupUi, retranslateUi. Also, don't forget about default names generation. you may rename every QLabel used, even if it has no additional logic on it, but...

Comment: Please look at the link I provided. In each of the standard approaches, there's just one "Ui"::setupUi() called, unambiguously. Apart from the QLabels in the Ui-class, which additional ones are there? Are you mixing auto-forms with manual-static-forms?

Comment: Solution i provide is NOT a standard approach. it allows using two or more form parts generated with designer, which is not allowed by standard approach. and yes, i KNOW the standart approach

Comment: [The first part of your answer IS a standard approach](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#using-a-member-variable). In the second part, you seem to be re-inventing the wheel; you might want to have a look at [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html); if QStackedWidget is not what fits your intention, how would you define "adding another form"?

Comment: well.. it seems that you hasn't understand second part of my answer.